# Study the function $y=(x^3-4x)^{1/2}$ & sketch its graph (without using a graphing calculator).

Tags: graphing-functions

$y=(x^3-4x)^{1/2}$

or, $y^2=x(x+2)(x-2)$

So, $0,+2,-2$ are the roots of this function.
Then I can find out $f'(x)$, $f''(x)$, thus finding the **maxima & minima** of the function.

I can separately draw **the parabolic curves** , $y^2=x$, $y^2= (x+2)$ & $y^2=(x-2)$

But i actually cannot find any way how to use these informations to end up sketching the graph.Is there any specific method of joining these 3 parabolic curves to get the wanted graph?Please help.

**Thank You**

Comment: Careful! Your $y = \sqrt{\cdots}$ is *not* the same as $y^2 = \cdots$, as the latter introduces a reflection of the original curve $y$ about the $x$-axis.

Comment: @GFauxPas and it does not describe a function anymore too.

Comment: Ok..I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sketching those $3$ curves is unlikely to help. Instead, sketch the radicand polynomial $g(x) = x(x + 2)(x - 2)$. Recall that the original function $f(x) = \sqrt{g(x)}$ is defined only where $g(x)$ is on or above the $x$-axis. Can you use this to figure out the domain of $f$?

Now to transform $g$ into $f$, focus only on the parts of $g$ that lie above the $x$-axis (erase the stuff below the $x$-axis). Recall that:

- Square rooting $0$ or $1$ does not change it. So all points on $g$ whose $y$-coordinates are $0$ or $1$ will be **invariant**.
- Square rooting a small number (between $0$ and $1$) will make it **bigger**.
- Square rooting a big number (greater than $1$) will make it **smaller**.

That should be enough to make a rough sketch. If you want it to be more precise, compute derivatives to find local extrema.

Comment: Thank you.Hope, now i can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

the graph of $y = f(x) = x^3 - 4x = x(x+2)(x-2)$ is odd and $y\ge 0$ on $[-2,0]\cup [2, \infty).$  the graph of $y = f(x)$ has a local maximum at $(-\frac2{\sqrt 3}, \frac{16}{3\sqrt 3}).$  the domain of the graph of $y = \sqrt{f(x)}$ is $[-2,0]\cup [2, \infty).$ the graph of $y = \sqrt{f(x)}$ looks like a semicircle in $-2 \le x \le 0$ and like a half of a parabola in $2 \le x < \infty.$

Comment: Thanks for the information.